# unable to parse query string for function query Parameter 2

Tags: google-sheets-formula

when i writing this code condition where clause Col10>0  then i am getting Value correct but When I am using Col28>0 condition then i am getting Error "unable to parse query string for function query Parameter 2  No_Column:Col28"

1.Using This Code getting Correct output :-

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rd4R0Q_Kx6owhIEIo14lHwpVBqbiTYxhkEMQVAOwpRw/edit#gid=1216001801","VCPD110522!a2:x")},"Select Col4 where Col10>0")

2. When I am Using This code getting error

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rd4R0Q_Kx6owhIEIo14lHwpVBqbiTYxhkEMQVAOwpRw/edit#gid=1216001801","VCPD110522!a2:x")},"Select Col4 where Col28>0")

Comment: The range you are importing comprises only 24 columns, so it doesn't make any sense to reference a column number greater than 24

Answer (score 0):

to use `Col28` you need range `A:AB`:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1rd4R0Q_Kx6owhIEIo14lHwpVBqbiTYxhkEMQVAOwpRw", 
 "VCPD110522!A:AB")}, "select Col4 where Col28>0", )
```